# How to retrieve a document in Firebase using just the id

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have not been able to find a reference in the documentation on how to get a document reference when you know the id of it in firebase.

I am passing the id to a webpage to lookup a QR code. Rather than storing a secondary unique id for each qrcode document I am relying on the firebase unique id.

Here is the lookup I tried but which seems to fail.

```
firebase.firestore().collection('cues').doc(id).get().then(function (docsnapshot) {
        console.info('About: ' + docsnapshot.get('text'));
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get my original code to work with this modification to the query

```
firebase.firestore().collection('cues').doc(id).get().then((doc) => {
```

... and then just use doc.get("field") to get values form my document

Answer (score 1):

you can access to data like this:

```
const { id } = docsnapshot
const data = docsnapshot.data()
const myDoc = { id, ...data } 

myDoc.text
myDoc.anything...
```

Comment: What does { id } do ... I am not familiar with that construct

Comment: `const { id } = docsnapshot` is the same thing as `const id = docsnapshot.id`. This is object destructuring, that means grab id from the docsnapshot object. You can do `const { a, b, c, d } = myObject` and have access to these variables, thats pretty handy.