# How to list all documents in a sub-collection and then fetch their documents by their ID?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to show data from a document inside a collection between "students" and their "courses"

I'm using html, javascript and this structure but as of now I can only retrieve the ID of the document but I'd like to also access the data inside this document

```
async function fetchCourses() {

  const studentId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
  const courseIds = await db.collection(`students/${studentId}/attending`).get();

  const courseDocs = await Promise.all(
    courseIds.docs.map(doc => db.doc(`courses/${doc.id},${studentId}`).get())
  );

  return courseDocs.filter(doc => doc.exists).map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }),
  console.log(courseDocs));
}
```

My console.log displays all this:

[image: Console.log]

Any help is gladly appreciate

**Edit**

This is the data structure inside my Firebase:

The **students** are stored in a collection indexed by their uid and each student document contains their name and more data, but most importantly a sub-collection named **attending** which contains empty documents indexed by courseId, refering to a document in the courses collection

[image]

The **courses** are stored in another collection indexed by courseId and like in **students** each course document contains a title and more data, and a sub-collection named **attendees** which contains empty documents indexed by uid, refering to a student.

[image]

Comment: Could you please show structure of the data inside Firebase ?

Comment: As Kundan mentioned above, it is necessary to know the structure of data inside Firebase. However, there is a similar [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900818/how-to-retrieve-a-document-in-firebase-using-just-the-id), which talks about retrieving the document using just the id in Firebase. You may have a look and let me know if that helps!

Comment: @Kundan thanks for letting me know, I edited the post with the additional information

Comment: @MousumiRoy thanks for the info! I already modified my original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "cities", "SF");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

if (docSnap.exists()) {
  console.log("Document data:", docSnap.data());
} else {
  // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
  console.log("No such document!");
}
```

above is an example from firestore docs. [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) has really specific syntax.
you can only access data of request with doc.data() syntax. All other attempts will bring you nothing or some irrelevant object(at least in my experience)